# R add values to tibble column in groups

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tibble

I want to add a new column to a tibble of experiment data with multiple rows per participant, where the values for the new column are calculated for each participant in turn.

Let's assume the following dummy example:

```
my_data <- tibble(
  participant_id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)),
  suffix = c('su', 'bi', 'fa', 'su', 'va', 'va', 'bi', 'su')
)
```

On a single vector of suffixes (i.e. only one participant), I have been able to use the following code to give me a corresponding vector of ones and zeros (1 where the suffix is unique, 0 where it's repeated):

```
ifelse(!suffix %in% suffix[duplicated(suffix)], 1, 0)
```

But I can't work out how to do this for each participant in turn to get a column containing a 1 where a suffix is unique **for that participant** and a 0 where it's repeated **for that participant**.

The only (ugly) way I can think of to do it is to create a new dummy column which glues together `participant_id` and `suffix` (so the values would be e.g. `'1_su', '1_bi'` etc.) and run the `ifelse` statement on that column. Is there a nicer way to do it just grouping by `participant_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to count for each suffix number of occurrences if it is more than one then it is not unique.

```
# Loading required libraries
library(dplyr)

# Create sample dataframe
my_data <- tibble(
  participant_id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)),
  suffix = c('su', 'bi', 'fa', 'su', 'va', 'va', 'bi', 'su')
)

my_data %>%
  # Group by suffix
  group_by(participant_id, suffix) %>%
  # If suffix has count equal one then unique else zero
  mutate(is_unique = ifelse(n() == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I think this has the same problem I already had of only telling me whether the suffix is unique in the entire table, right? Whereas what I need to know is whether the suffix is unique only in that particular participant's set of suffixes.

Comment: I have edited it if you grouped by participant_id and suffix this should work.

Comment: Doesn't group_by just give you one value per grouped variable? I tried doing it using group_by and participant_id but just got zeros for every row which isn't right.

Comment: Group by and count, counts the number of similar occurrences in the group. In the answer I have provided I am grouping by both participant_id and suffix and counting the occurrences if it is more than 1 then it is not unique else it is unique.